# problem with decompiling/decrypt lua file

Tags: lua, decode, bytecode, decompiler

[File image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLqpT.png)i dont know nothing about decompiling lua files, and i need help. I need to decompile this file, im trying to use luadec but i have "The input file does not have the signature of a valid Lua file."  error. Its file from compiled otclient, its a client for open tibia servers. I think its a bytecode, but i dont know how to read that. Thanks for helping me :)

[Link for file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ba2DNuqOrhM6xDm0Mwe2uvN7mxB5Ofar/view)

[Virus Scan](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/b553daf0d4dd57b2d0b1a8e3195b3e88ad256ce3f1cc03333770add515b4d257?nocache=1)

I tryin few decompilers/decoders from github

Comment: Did you try `luac` with the right version? Your file is not public btw.

Comment: No, im not tryin, can u tell me how to do it? Sorry, file is public right now.

Comment: The file is encrypted, it is not a usual Lua bytecode file.

Comment: So is there any way to decrypt this file? Thanks for any tip if possible.

Comment: First, you need to understand how this file is supposed to be loaded. It's not valid Lua on its own.

Comment: Its a file from otclient (Open tibia server client) and i found something about decrypting otclient files, bit i dont knows how to use that :/ https://otland.net/threads/otclient-decryption.259063/

Comment: He is basically confirming ESkris suspicion, and the answer is: without a password you can't decrypt it.